# pyephem: installation via pip fails

Tags: pyephem

I am trying to install pyephem on an OSX 10.7.5 system using pip. The installation process starts well, with many successful calls to gcc. But the installation fails with the error message:

```
ld: library not found for -lbundle1.o

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

This occurs after the command:

```
gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -g -arch i386 build/temp.macosx-10.5-i386-2.7/extensions/_libastro.o build/... [a whole list of .o files]
```

I also have tried using easy_install and the installation failed with the same error message.

I'm not an expert at all and can't find out what "bundle1" is. Any help would be much appreciated.

Andrew Fletcher

Answer (score 0):

(**Update:** The OP, as indicated in the comment below, has avoided the problem by using ActiveState Python on his Mac, which might be a possible solution for other people who run into this problem.)

Well, wow — I have never seen that error before! Until other Stack Overflow denizens can offer more specific answers, I'll just point you in the direction of an Apple Mailing List post that I just found in which someone got the error because some sort of SDK was missing from their system:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-dev/2011/Apr/msg00016.html

If you do further Googling for the library name you might be able to turn up further details.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. Googling revealed several other cases of this error showing up in OSX 10.7 builds using gcc. I couldn't find a "recipe" for solving it though and my knowledge of compilers and OSX is not deep enough to make sense of the discussions. I got pyephem running (which is a must-have for me) by switching to the ActiveState python distribution and using pypm to install pyephem.